# ANT to maven convertion

Tags: maven, ant

I have a module that was orignally writter using ANT. I am currently converting it to maven. I have resolved all the dependencies and it is packaging fine.

Here is the thing. The module offers 3 different folders (questions, answers, remarks) and all of them contains 3 .properties files with the same name. I want to package the module and it should only incluse the files of the fodler specified.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [ant fileset](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html)

```
<war destfile="myapp.war" webxml="src/metadata/myapp.xml">
    <fileset dir="questions" includes="my.properties" />
    <fileset dir="answers" includes="my.properties" />
    <fileset dir="remarks" includes="my.properties" />
</war
```

Comment: @Deepak Mittal Was my anwwer useful? If you up-vote and accept useful answers people will be more motivated to help you